# Expressing $E$ field and $B$ field using potentials

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, potential, potential-energy

Why dont we have a term that corresponds to the change in E field in eq1.61b like we have in eq 1.61a?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This really just comes down to the definition of **A**.

We *define* **A** through $\boldsymbol \nabla \times \textbf{A} = \textbf{B}$.
Then, using the Maxwell equation $\boldsymbol \nabla \times \textbf{E} = - \frac{\partial\textbf{B}}{\partial t}$ we obtain
$$\boldsymbol \nabla \times \textbf{E} = - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \boldsymbol \nabla \times \textbf{A}
= -\boldsymbol \nabla \times \frac{\partial\textbf{A} }{\partial t}.$$

To satisfy this equation, we can write $\textbf{E} = -\frac{\partial \textbf{A}}{\partial t} + \textbf{E}_0 $, where $\textbf{E}_0$ is any field whose curl is zero. Such a field can always be written as the gradient of a scalar, and therefore we may define $\textbf{E}_0 = - \nabla \phi$ for some scalar function $\phi$.

And there you have it, with these definitions of **A** and $\phi$, we can write any electric field as $\textbf{E} = - \nabla \phi - \frac{\partial \textbf{A}}{\partial t}$.

Comment: Why don't we do the same for magnetic field using Maxwell's fourth law?

Comment: In general for any vector field $\textbf{V}$ it is true that $\boldsymbol \nabla \cdot (\boldsymbol \nabla \times \textbf{V}) = 0$. We can therefore only define $\textbf{B} = \boldsymbol \nabla \times \textbf{A}$ because of the law $\boldsymbol \nabla \cdot \textbf{B} = 0$. A similar law does not hold for the electric field, and therefore we cannot define a potential for **E** in the same way. I hope that answers your question.